# How to dynamically change data type?

Tags: c

I want to make a program that counts up unlimited (up to the RAM's max capacity), say that first I assigned an unsigned integer for the buffer, how to change it at run-time like to `long` or to `long long` or other data type that can hold more integers?

Comment: How big is your ram? Our universe probably vanishes before you fill up your ram by counting up

Comment: use (cm)alloc and void pointers

Comment: You cannot change the data type dynamically, once a variable has a type, it always will have that type.

Comment: Use GMP `mpz_t` and let GMP handle expanding the storage as needed?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Just use storage space for the possibly largest ever count you are likely to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data type that can hold integers of any size (up to the capacity of your computer), the traditional word to search for is `bignum`. C doesn't have it, but many languages do.